# Can't upload any documents to Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've been playing with Azure CosmosDB for the past couple of weeks. I've been uploading documents and trying things out perfectly fine. Today, I can't upload any documents - it simply hangs forever, with a notification saying "Uploading and creating documents", but no documents ever appear.

To be clear, I'm talking about the "Upload Item" button on the "Items" page of a Container. I click it, select a JSON document as I always do, and click upload. It hangs there after that.

Things I've tried:
- Deleting the database + container and starting again
- Upping the RU/s from the free minimum of 400 RU/s to 1,000 RU/s (I'm on a PAYG account)
- Using the local CosmosDB emulator - this works absolutely fine, it's able to accept those JSON documents and create them in the DB no problem
- Using a different browser, and older versions of those documents that worked previously
- Creating documents manually with the "New Item" button - this works, but it is very cumbersome compared to uploading the documents as I am frequently making changes

I'm not sure what else to try - any suggestions? Is this working for anyone else?

I'm on "East US 2" even though I'm in Europe, because I kept getting problems and had to keep jumping servers until the stuff I needed was available.

Comment: Are you able to add an item via the portal, manually (not uploading; just typing up a new document), or does that hang too? Maybe open a support ticket? Unfortunately not something that can be covered here.

Comment: Yeah it works if I manually add a document through the portal with the "New Item" button. Just wondered if there was any other debug steps I could take so I can try to do something my end - I don't have a support package.

Comment: Upload Documents seems to be just an Azure Portal shortcut/feature, not a particular operation you'd do through the REST API or the Cosmos DB SDKs. If you are building an application, you won't have this Upload Document shortcut, you'd have to write the code that saves each document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the portal. We have deployed a fix to this that is now available.

Thank you for reporting.

Comment: Given this, I'd suggest voting to close the original question as something that is not reproducible (common for transient errors, typos, etc), especially with a service-based issue that's been fixed.

Comment: You should see a "close" item under the question (next to 'share', 'follow', 'edit', and 'flag'). Then you can choose a reason. Buuuuuuuut... I think you need 3K rep first to gain that privilege.

Comment: yeah, not there yet :)